# Shutdown multiple Virtual Machines on Ovirt by Ansible module

Tags: ansible, ovirt

I am an Ansible newbie and I need to interact with Ovirt Manager by ovirt_vm module.
My purpose is the multiple shutting down of a list of VMs stored in .yml file.

Here my playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Manage VMs on ovirt-Manager
  hosts: MyHost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - ovirt_vars.yml
    #FQDN and credentials
    - ovirt-vms.yml
    #List of VMs

  vars:
    vm: "{{ VMs }}"

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Login to ovirt-M
      ovirt_auth:
        hostname: "{{ ovirt_fqdn }}"
        username: "{{ ovirt_user }}"
        password: "{{ ovirt_password }}"
      tags:
        - always

  tasks:
    - name: Show List of VMs from ovirt-vms.yml
      debug:
         msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
         "{{ vm }}"
```

The problem is in this task

```yaml
    - name: Shutdown multiple VMs
      ovirt_vm:
        auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
        cluster: CL_OVIRT
        state: stopped
        name: "{{ vm |string }}" << HERE
```

How can I put a single item of my list in parameter name? e.g. VM01,VM02,...VM10

```yaml
  post_tasks:
    - name: Logout from ovirt-M
      ovirt_auth:
        state: absent
        ovirt_auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
      tags:
         - always
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `How can I put a single item of my list in parameter name?` => by using the very exact same loop you have in your debug task right on top of it.

Comment: Thank you, please can you help me with the syntax? I can't understand how can I use the loop inside the parameter name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, just use the same [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) mechanism you are using in your preceding `debug` task:

```yaml
    - name: Shutdown multiple VMs
      ovirt_vm:
        auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
        cluster: CL_OVIRT
        state: stopped
        name: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ vm }}"
      # alternatively, use the new loop syntax. See doc link above
      # loop: "{{ vm }}"
```